# DocuSign InPerson signer host name incorrect

Tags: docusignapi

I am working through tests in DocuSign production environment and have run into some weird behavior. We have a scenario where an advisor can host in person signing sessions with clients and will also sign the document at the end of the process. After the in person signers sign and the advisor signs, there is a final reviewer that will check the document and give his signoff (registered principal). This all works great, except when we set up in person signings, this is what the first signer gets this screen during review:

[Current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvTV5.png)

In demo.docusign.net environment, this screen would say "Advisor Name please give John M Doe control of the keyboard and mouse". Here is the JSON for the recipients node taken from the DocuSign API logs on this transaction:

```
{
    "signers": [{
        "name": "Registered Principal",
        "email": "principal@test.com",
        "recipientId": "3",
        "routingOrder": "10",
        "roleName": "Registered Principal"
    }, {
        "name": "Advisor Name",
        "email": "advisoremail@test.com",
        "recipientId": "5",
        "customFields": ["B00"],
        "routingOrder": "4",
        "roleName": "Rep"
    }],
    "inPersonSigners": [{
        "hostName": "Advisor Name",
        "hostEmail": "advisoremail@test.com",
        "signerName": "John M Doe",
        "signerEmail": "client@test.com",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "routingOrder": "1",
        "roleName": "Client"
    }, {
        "hostName": "Advisor Name",
        "hostEmail": "advisoremail@test.com",
        "signerName": "Jane Doe",
        "signerEmail": "jointclient@test.com",
        "recipientId": "2",
        "routingOrder": "2",
        "roleName": "Joint Client"
    }]
}
```

I have edited the email addresses to anonymize them as well as the Host Name.

I suspect there is some email address matching or something going on behind the scenes with the DocuSign API - the Host Email does have a registered DS account and we have used it before with previous tests and the SignerName varies depending on test. Any insight on why this might be happening?

Comment: After additional testing, we've found that there is some sort of email matching going on in the DS backend. We were able to create new accounts that had not been used before and everything works as expected

Answer (score 0):

After additional testing, we've found that there is some sort of email matching going on in the DS backend. We were able to create new accounts that had not been used before and everything works as expected –